# html input type button not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html

trying to open an html file for a website. The following onclick is not working in Internet Explorer, but it works in google chrome, and firefox. Any suggestions?

```
<tr id=tr1>
  <td><input id=But1 style="background:url('butc.jpg')" value="Home" onclick="window.location.href='main.html'" type="button"></td>
  <td><input type="button" id=But1 style="background:url('buto.jpg')" value="Advertise with us" onclick="window.location.href='advertise.html'" ></td>
  <td><input id="But1" style="background:url('buto.jpg')" value="Become a marketer" onclick="window.location.href='market.html'" type="button"></td>
  <td><input id="But1" style="background:url('buto.jpg')" value="BudBuddies" onclick="window.location.href='buds.html'" type="button"></td>
  <td><input id="But1" style="background:url('buto.jpg')" value="BudTube" onclick="window.location.href='tube.html'" type="button"></td>
  <td><input id="But1" style="background:url('buto.jpg')" value="Laws" onclick="window.location.href='laws.html'" type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

i am two days into teaching myself html, and as far as why am i doing things the way im doing them well the truth is i have no idea what im doing at this point. what im trying to do is open an html file in the same window on a button click and this is working fine in firefox and chrome but when i open it in internet explorer 8 and 9 it does not work so any suggestion on what im doing wrong is appreciated. all the html file i am opening are local.

Comment: What is not working, do you get errors?

Comment: And which IE is that? It works on my IE9. http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/x4LvR/

Comment: Why do you have six buttons all with the same `id=But1`? An `id` should only exist once on the page.

Comment: @Bryce Meyer: What do you mean by not working? Onclick event must fire in every browswer according to the shown code?

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

If you have a list of things, then use a list.

If you want a navigational control, then use a link.

See [listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) for examples of how to style lists of links to look like a row of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Having more than one input elements with the same Id can be the reason.

As a suggestion, use [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) and see if there are any errors.

[Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)

> This validator checks the markup validity of Web documents in HTML,
>   XHTML, SMIL, MathML, etc.

Comment: If you're suggesting an inline `onclick` will not function properly due to too many elements having the same `id`, I don't think that's the case. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mV4sQ/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yes, you are correct that's what I was also going to say. Anyway deleted that part as I am not sure whether he has posted the shown code is all attempts or he has everything in the same html file.